# How to pass arg from command to subcommand Discord py

Tags: python, discord.py, subcommand

Say I have the following command and subcommands:

```py
@commands.group()
async def channel(self, ctx, channel_name_or_id):
    # convert channel_name_or_id to channel object

@channel.command()
async def get_mention(ctx, channel_object):
    await ctx.send(channel_object.mention)

@channel.command()
async def get_id(ctx, channel_object):
    await ctx.send(channel_object.id)
```

I want the parent command to convert the name or id to an object, and *then pass that object to the subcommands*. Is there a way to do this? Something like `ctx.invoked_subcommand.pass(channel_object)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the channel object by using `self.client.get_channel(id)`. You could use a class level variable that you instantiate in the `__init__()` (if it's a cog) and set that to the channel object.

Comment: That's not a bad idea... My only concern is that won't it conflict if the same command is called twice at the same time?